# Install multiple fonts to server

Tags: fonts

I read many threads on how to install fonts to server and most will look like this

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Raspoutine Medium';
  src: url(fonts/Raspoutine Medium.ttf);
}

body {
font-family: 'Raspoutine Medium', Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
}
```

which only contains 1 url. But the problem is my font family has 20 different OTF files (light, regular, book, medum, heavy, black etc). So how would I install all of them on server and refer to all of them? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way would be create different `font-weight` and `font-style` combinations.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raspoutine';
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url(fonts/Raspoutine Medium.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raspoutine';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url(fonts/Raspoutine Normal.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raspoutine';
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url(fonts/Raspoutine Light.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raspoutine';
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: Italic;
    src: url(fonts/Raspoutine Light Italic.ttf);
}
```

Well You get the idea. More about numeric `font-weight` values could be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight)